# Chai not catching thrown error using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, try-catch, chai

Because a promise is returned Chai doesnt catch the exception, how can I resolve this?

Here is my test.

```
describe('test.js', function() {
    it('Ensures throwError() throws error if no parameter is supplied.', async function() {
        expect(async function() {
            const instance = new Class();
            await instance.throwError();
        }).to.throw(Error);
    });
});
```

Here is my code.

```
class Class{
    async throwError(parameter) {
        try {
            if (!parameter) {
                throw Error('parameter required');
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

The message from Chai.

```
AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw Error
```

But I can see this message on the call stack.

```
(node:21792) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: parameter required
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the exact same issue, tried some solutions but none works out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect().to.throw()` only support sync function. For async function, you need to use [chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised).

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
export class Class {
  async throwError(parameter) {
    if (!parameter) {
      throw Error('parameter required');
    }
  }
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
import { Class } from '.';

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

describe('62596956', function() {
  it('Ensures throwError() throws error if no parameter is supplied.', async function() {
    const instance = new Class();
    await expect(instance.throwError(null)).to.eventually.rejectedWith(Error);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  62596956
    ✓ Ensures throwError() throws error if no parameter is supplied.


  1 passing (9ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 3                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```